# Argument not passing on Delayed::Job method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I'm using Delayed::Job to send the sms from a rails application.I've included gem as follows on Gemfile.

```
gem 'delayed_job', "~> 4.1.1"
```

I've also added a custom Delayed Jobs as

```
class SendSmsJob < Struct.new(:person_id, :content)

  include DelayedAirbrakeNotification


  def perform
    person = Person.find(person_id)
    phone = person.phone_number
    ....
    ....
    ....

  end

end
```

and I'm triggering this job as below from controller,

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(SendSmsJob.new(@person.id, "Test message"))
```

but  when I try to use the value of `person_id` and `content` under the `perform` method, I get `nil` and `""` respectively.
I'm following the same approach for the other jobs, and these are working perfectly, 
I don't know If I'm missing anything here.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try passing the person object without the id ? Like this Delayed::Job.enqueue(SendSmsJob.new(@person, "Test message")), then just call @person.phone_number, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderLuna Yes, I've tried, same issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should install DelayedJob as backend for ActiveJob as described [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#installation).
Then generate ActiveJob jobs by running this command:

```
rails generate job NAME [options]
```

run `rails generate job --help` for getting help or see the [documentation page](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).

Last but not least, in the `perform` method you should define any parameters you need.

```
def perform(person_id)
  ...
end
```